# SQL Server, how to sum based on day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, dayofweek

I have a table that maintains attendance. It has three columns:

```
createdby (varchar(30))
TimeSheetDate (dateTime)
Workinghours (integer)
```

I want to find the sum of working hours on a day of the week basis. e.g.

```
Monday   Tuesday    Wednesday
------------------------------
10        9         11
```

I am having difficulty getting the total on DOW basis.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    createdby,
    CASE 
        WHEN dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate) = 'Monday'  
           THEN sum(WorkingHours) as Monday 
        WHEN dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate) = 'Tuesday' 
           THEN sum(WorkingHours) as Tuesday
        WHEN dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate) = 'Wednesday' 
           THEN sum(WorkingHours) as Wednesday
        WHEN dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate) = 'Thursday' 
           THEN sum(WorkingHours) as Thursday
    End 
FROM 
    TS.TimesheetsDetails
WHERE 
    CreatedDate <= '2014-09-26' AND 
    CreatedDate >= '2014-09-19' 
GROUP BY 
    createdby, dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate)
```

But it does not work, and gives error.

Can Anyone give any proper guidance?
 By the way the function `udf_DayOfWeek()` returns Day of the week.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: TimeSheetDate WorkingHours CreatedBy
2014-09-19 9.00  santu
2014-09-20 9.00  santu
2014-09-21 2.00  santu
2014-09-22 1.00  selva
2014-09-19 3.00  selva
2014-09-20 3.00  selva
2014-09-21 9.00  ainan
2014-09-19 9.00  ainan
2014-09-20 9.00  ainan


Output

createdby monday  tuesday  wednesday
santu   9  12  10
selva  9  10  8
ainan  8  10  9

Comment: you can use `DATEPART(WEEKDAY,TimeSheetDate)` instead of `dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just looks like a conditional sum. The key is *columns* cannot be conditional, just the *value* inside the aggregate. So you have to put the case statement inside the `SUM()`:

```
select createdby,
    sum(case when dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate)='Monday' then WorkingHours else 0 end) as Monday,
    sum(case when dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate)='Tuesday' then WorkingHours else 0 end) as Tuesday,
    ...
from TS.TimesheetsDetails
where CreatedDate between '2014-09-19' and '2014-09-26'
group by createdby
```

Note 1: I do not understand why you would group by day of week if you also want to aggregate by it. I've removed that.

Note 2: I am not sure why you are using a UDF instead of the built-in `DATEPART` function to get the day of week.

---

Alternatively, you can pivot which, arguably, looks a lot cleaner:

```
select createdby, Monday, Tuesday, ...
from (
    select createdby, dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate) as dow, WorkingHours
    from TS.TimesheetsDetails
    where CreatedDate between '2014-09-19' and '2014-09-26'
) x
pivot (
    sum(WorkingHours)
    for dow in ([Monday],[Tuesday],...)
) p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

But i am not sure

```
     SELECT createdby, CASE WHEN dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate)='Monday' THEN sum(WorkingHours) end as Monday,case WHEN dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate)='Tuesday' THEN sum(WorkingHours) end as Tuesday,case WHEN dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate)='Wednesday' THEN sum(WorkingHours) end as Wednesday,case  WHEN dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate)='Thursday' THEN sum(WorkingHours) end as Thursday

 FROM TS.TimesheetsDetails WHERE CreatedDate <='2014-09-26' and CreatedDate>='2014-09-19' GROUP BY createdby, dbo.udf_DayOfWeek(TimeSheetDate)`
```